# firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, google-signin

firebase social login (Facebook &gmail) doesn't work with my android device 
there is no response on clicking login button, however it works on localhost (web browser)........
..................

```
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
 firebase social login doesn't work with my android device ,,works only on web !!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Just make sure you have inAppBrowser plugin installed. I think that is the reason